# How to do simple unit tests on device rather than on the host

Tags: android, macos, flutter, sqflite

I am running some unit tests that use sqflite lib, and so far the openDatabase function does not work on MacOS desktop, because getDatabasesPath does not seem to have a MacOS method. So in order to test the functionality I need to run the unit tests on an android device, and as far as I can tell unit tests in flutter are run locally by default. Is there a way to direct the tests to use the phone instead?

Answer (score 1):

found some GitHub flutter test docs and apparently you can do

```
    flutter run test/name_of_you_test.dart
```

to run the contents of a test file directly on device